# Docker-compose works, but website won't open on localhost

Tags: docker, docker-compose

I'm trying to clone this repo.

https://github.com/vinitkumar/node-twitter

I downloaded all the dependencies.

I ran

`docker-compose --log-level DEBUG build`

`docker-compose up`

Docker returns no errors

`Starting mongodb ... done`
`Creating node-twitter_web_1 ... done`

No website on

`http://localhost:3000`

What are the best diagnostic tools I can use to solve this error?

Comment: Did you check container logs? Also, github readme has the following: `Before building Docker container change DB link to: mongodb://mongodb/ntwitter in .env file.`. Did you change env file?

Comment: I changed the DB link, but I didn't change .env.example's name to .env. I've just done that now, and it's throwing different errors. I think I'll leave this question, and learn how to read docker logs.